# CakePHP 3.0 - order by assocation count?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Lets say i have table Users that hasOne Userdata and hasMany Contests.

How would i retrieve Users for pagination ordered by:
1: First ones are that already have more than 1 contest and userdata filled
2: Second ones are that already have userdata filled and no contests
3: Last ones are with empty userdata and contests

Im paginating it so far but cant solve this problem:

```
$this->paginate = [
        'contain' => [
            'Userdatas',
            'Contests'
        ],
        'maxLimit' => 20,
    ];

    $query = $this->Users->find('all');
    $this->set('users', $this->paginate($query));
```